# Building a Docker image with a configured version of node package installed

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install, docker-for-windows

I want to build a Docker image which contains a node package installed. If the package version is omitted or hardcoded in the `Dockerfile`, everything is OK (`@14.0.0`):

```
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:12.16.1-nanoserver-1909
RUN npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@14.0.0
```

Build command and result:

`docker build -t sitecore-jss-cli:14.0.0-nanoserver-1909 .`

```
Successfully built 1c0ebbcd5be2
Successfully tagged sitecore-jss-cli:14.0.0-nanoserver-1909
```

But when the version is passed as an argument (to be able to build any version), the error occurs. Please take a look at the updated `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG SITECOREJSS_VERSION
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:12.16.1-nanoserver-1909
RUN npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@${SITECOREJSS_VERSION}
```

Command with the argument and error:

`docker build --build-arg SITECOREJSS_VERSION=14.0.0 -t sitecore-jss-cli:14.0.0-nanoserver-1909 .`

```
...
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "${SITECOREJSS_VERSION}": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

Looks like the argument needs to be escaped in some way. Any clue how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. **Ordering**

   An `ARG` *outside* the `FROM` block is only accessible in the `FROM` line itself. In this case, as you don't need to use the `--build-arg` as part of the `FROM`, move it inside:

   ```
   FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:12.16.1-nanoserver-1909
   ARG SITECOREJSS_VERSION
   ...
   ```

   If you need to use it in `FROM` *and* elsewhere in the Dockerfile, you need to be explicit about that:

   ```
   ARG SITECOREJSS_VERSION
   FROM ...
   ARG SITECOREJSS_VERSION
   ...
   ```
2. **Interpolation**

   Per [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/542), if you want to do interpolation in the commands in Windows images, you need to use `%`:

   ```
   RUN npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@%SITECOREJSS_VERSION%
   ```

So the complete working version would be:

```
FROM stefanscherer/node-windows:12.16.1-nanoserver-1909
ARG SITECOREJSS_VERSION
RUN npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli@%SITECOREJSS_VERSION%
```

Comment: @SerhiiShushliapin that's weird, when I run a basic `FROM node`, it makes a difference whether I put the ARG before (empty tag) or after (tag is value from build arg) FROM. But neither tries to use `"${SITECOREJSS_VERSION}"` as a literal tag name.

Comment: Yep.. Arg in FROM works like a charm... No problems with that... The question is how to pass it to npm properly.

Comment: @SerhiiShushliapin then I don't know - I can't use the actual image you do, as I'm on macOS. Using `FROM node:12.16.1-alpine`, the build arg works if it's *after* `FROM`.

Comment: @SerhiiShushliapin oh, maybe it's because you're using nix-style interpolation in Windows, try my edit

Comment: Switched to Linux containers, it works. Then switched back to Windows and tried your updated version with '%' - also works! Thanks @jonrsharpe!